# jquery get attr value from array

Tags: jquery, each, attr

```
var t=new Array('title','placeholder','alt');

$.each(t,function(k,v){
    alert(typeof $(this).attr(v));//PROBLEM $(this) is not the right object
});
```

**goal:** Get attribute's (title or placeholder or alt) value that exist.

if element has title, then return title, if not, check placeholder, and then alt.

**for example:**

```
>> var v='title';
>> $(this).attr(v);
>> $(this).attr('title');(I want this)
```

**old SOLUTION:**

```
for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++){
    alert($(this).attr(t[i]));
}
```

**REAL SOLUTION:** (**thanks to mplungjan**)

```
var o=$(this);
$.each(t,function(k,v){
    alert(typeof o.attr(v));//PROBLEM $(this) is not the right object
});
```

Comment: Because there are no attr in an Array and v is not a jQuery object -  `alert(typeof v);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I believe you are trying to do.

Click on the field and look in the console

```js
$(function() {
  var t=['title','placeholder','alt'];
  $("input").on("focus",function() { // we need an event 
    var inp = $(this); // the input as a jQuery object
    $.each(t,function(_,key) { // in here, $(this) is NOT the input
      console.log(key+":"+inp.prop(key)); // we use prop instead of attr
    });
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp1" type="text" title="Some input field" placeholder="Enter some text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

**Your code**:

```
var t=new Array('title','placeholder','alt');

    $.each(t,function(k,v){
        alert("key:"+k+"value:"+v);
    });
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/so2pp1tp/

Comment: sorry, my goal is get attribute value,using names from the array, problem is the attr function doesnt work. cant get value but only "undefined"

Comment: you want html dynamic attr like "title"?

Comment: if element has title, then return title, if not, check placeholder, and then alt. return any attr that exist

Comment: post your sample html